# function for finding datetime range in python list

Tags: python

I'm trying to sort a 2d list in python with 2 categories. The list consists of weather data with city name, zip code, latitude-longitude, date and time at which the weather data is noted, max-temperature of the day, min temperature, humidity and etc. . every day the weather data is being noted 8 times(at an interval of 'once in 3 hours'). if the user enters the city name and some time period (say: city= Chennai and time period= 2019-01-03 to 2019-01-06) the code should give back all the data in the given period of time.

I've tried importing datetime module to get the correct format of the date given by the user.
The problem now is finding out the range of data in the given date time period

(loc[4] contains the date and time corresponding to the weather data. it's of the format (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss))

```py
def cityn():
    city = input("Enter the cit1y name: ") 
    fy = int(input("from year: "))
    fm = int(input("from month: "))
    fd = int(input("from date: "))
    ty = int(input("to year: "))
    tm = int(input("to month: "))
    td = int(input("to date: "))
    d1 = datetime.datetime(fy,fm,fd)
    d2 = datetime.datetime(ty,tm,td)
    diff= (d2-d1).days+1    

    for loc in file:
        if loc[0]==city:
            for d in range(diff):
                if loc[4] in (d1+datetime.timedelta(d)):
                    print()
                    print("city name: ",loc[0])
                    print("city id: ",loc[1])
                    print("latitude: ",loc[2])
                    print("longitude: ",loc[3])
                    print("date and time: ",loc[4])
                    print("temperature: ",loc[5])
                    print("min temperature: ",loc[6])
                    print("max temperature: ",loc[7])
                    print("pressure: ",loc[8])
                    print("sea level: ",loc[9])
                    print("ground level: ",loc[10])
                    print("humidity: ",loc[11])
                    print("main: ",loc[12])
                    print("description: ",loc[13])
                    print("clouds: ",loc[14])
                    print("wind speed: ",loc[15])
                    print("wind degree: ",loc[16])


The output should provide the list of data of the specified city and in the given date range
```

Comment: Could you show us an example of `loc[4]`?

Comment: Is that mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm? Because that's different to what's in your question.

Comment: 2019-01-06 21:00:00 ,  2019-01-06 18:00:00 , 2019-01-06 15:00:00 , 2019-01-06 12:00:00 this is for a single day.

Comment: Ah, ok. The sane format, then. Won't be a sec.

Comment: So the date you want to check is in a different format than the range? @AkashKumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to convert all 3 dates (the date ranges, and the date to check) in datetime format, and then do comparisons

```
import datetime

def check_date_in_range(d_low, d_high, date):

    range_pattern = '%Y-%m-%d'
    date_pattern = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    #Date ranges d_low, d_high and date to check are converted to datetime
    dt_low = datetime.datetime.strptime(d_low, range_pattern)
    dt_high = datetime.datetime.strptime(d_high, range_pattern)
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, date_pattern)

    #Check if date is in range or not, return True if it is, else return False
    if dt_low <= dt <= dt_high:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(check_date_in_range('2019-01-03', '2019-01-06', '2019-01-04 21:00:00'))
print(check_date_in_range('2019-01-03', '2019-01-06', '2019-01-14 21:00:00'))
```

The output will be

```
True
False
```

Since `2019-01-04 21:00:00` falls within the range, but `2019-01-14 21:00:00` doesn't

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`?

Comment: Updated as you were commenting @wizzwizz4 Thanks!

Comment: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime why does this error occur?

Comment: Yes, check how I am calling it in my example, first argument is the string! Are you running my example and getting this error? @AkashKumar

Comment: thanks a lot! this helped solve my problem. your code worked perfectly!

Comment: Great! Glad to help! If my answer helped you, consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking the tick next to the answer @AkashKumar :)

Comment: I updated your answer @DeveshKumarSingh with some fewer lines of code. The one must ensure to provide the dates in the correct format. :)

Answer (score 1):

I took Devesh's code, but had the idea to test with fewer lines of code.

```
def check_date_in_range(start, end, x):
    """Return true if x is in the range [start, end]"""
    if start <= end:
        return start <= x <= end
    else:
        return start <= x or x <= end

print(check_date_in_range('2019-01-03', '2019-01-06', '2019-01-04 21:00:00'))
print(check_date_in_range('2019-01-03', '2019-01-06', '2019-01-14 21:00:00'))
```

---

Also it returns:

```
True
False
```

Comment: You know that you are parsing the strings lexicographically here, your code will take inputs like `2019-1000-2000` as well! Which obviously is an invalid date!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh, if you provide date like 'May 14th 2019' to your original example it will not work. The question set the formats like `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` and `yyyy-mm-dd` already.

Comment: The problem is more general, there are some programming languages that can get the timestamp from almost any meaningful string. Like PHP for [example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). I haven't saw that in Python.

Comment: Yes, but why not leverage what python gives you, btw we do have a https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html which has a function which can parse any datetime string, `datetime.parser.parse` irrespective of format, that will parse such date times @prosti